# Error using rsync with variable concatenation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rsync, os.system

I'm running the below script from the command line with this:

```
os.system("rsync -avrz -e \'ssh -i /root/.ssh/keyfile.pem\' /var/www/" + folder_name + " root@server.com:" + destfoldertosync)
```

and I get this when I print out the rsync:

```
rsync -avrz -e 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/keyfile.pem' /var/www/folder_name, root@server.com:/var/www/destfoldertosync
```

"/var/www/folder_name," is breaking rsync.  It works fine with the folder name hardcoded in there.  Why is it inserting a comma after the path and how can I stop it from doing that?

Note: I can't use paramiko so I want this to work with os.system.

Comment: What does `repr(folder_name)` look like?

Comment: I don't see any difference when I wrap the folder name in there....

Comment: Oh but wait...I did make a mistake.  I was seperating the params by commas.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the mistake of separating the parameters by commas on the cli.  Now it works.